# Expected value for dependent random variables

Tags: probability

If $z_1,z_2,...,z_K$ are dependent random variables, $E_{z_1,z_2,...,z_K}[I(z_1=1)]$ can be written as $P(z_1=1)$ i.e. the marginal probability of $z_1=1$. Is there a way to express

$$E_{z_1,z_2,...,z_K}\left[I(z_1=1)\displaystyle\prod_{k=2}^Ka^{I(z_k=1)}\right]$$

in terms of probability ( marginal or conditional )?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking writing $E(f(X))$ as $\int f(x) dP_X$ is an expression in terms of the probability distribution of $X$. So you need to be more precise by what you mean by "express in terms of probability". In the case of an indicator, we get a nice simple expression, that's true. But your variable is *significantly* more complicated than an indicator, so I don't see any reason to expect a simple expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the linearity of expectation
\begin{align}
E\left[ I(z_1=1) \prod_{k=2}^K a^{I(z_k=1)} \right]
% 
& =  \sum_{j=0}^{K-1} a^{j} E\left[ I(z_1=1)   I\left(\sum_{k=2}^KI(z_k=1)=j\right) \right] \\
% 
& =  \sum_{j=0}^{K-1} a^{j} P\left( z_1=1 \, \cap \,\sum_{k=2}^KI(z_k=1)=j\right)
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand. What's happening in the first equality?

Comment: @JackM I used that $$
\prod_{k=2}^K a^{I(z_k=1)} 
= a^{ \sum_{k=2}^K I(z_k=1)} 
=\sum_{j=0}^{K-1} a^{j}    I\left(\sum_{k=2}^KI(z_k=1)=j\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well then - denoting $A=\{z_1=1\}$ - you are asking for an expression for $\mathbb E1_Af(z_2,\dots,z_n)$.

With law of total probability we find:$$\mathbb E1_Af(z_2,\dots,z_n)=\mathbb E(1_Af(z_2,\dots,z_n)\mid A)\mathsf P(A)+\mathbb E(1_Af(z_2,\dots,z_n)\mid A^{\complement})\mathsf P(A^{\complement})=$$$$\mathbb E(f(z_2,\dots,z_n)\mid z_1=1)\mathsf P(z_1=1)$$

Comment: What happened to the conditional expected values? Are you assuming the $z_i$ are independent?

Comment: @JackM Oeps, I forgot. Thank you. Repaired now.